# Console runs out of java heap space memory, but Eclipse does not with same settings

Tags: java, eclipse, command-line, heap-memory

I am running a java program that loads very large (almost 2Gb) files.  It runs fine within Eclipse as long as I set the max heap space -mx3700m or higher.  Eclipse executes with javaw, and when I watch the memory usage in Task Manager I can see the Private Working Set memory hitting around 3.7Gb.

The problem comes when I create a runnable jar and try to run from the command line.  I've tried using both java and javaw, with max heap space all the way up to -mx7000m (my computer has 8Gb RAM).  But I always run out of memory.  When I monitor in Task Manager, the memory hits a ceiling at 2.08Gb and never goes beyond.

I'm using the same 64bit jre in both cases - 1.8.0_144.

I need to be able to run the jar file from the command line, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.  Any help would be very much appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: it is `-Xmx3700m`, subtle difference to what you seem to have set.

Comment: I thought I read that you can use either one.  I have actually tried it both ways, in both Eclipse and the console.  Same results no matter what

Answer (score 0):

I would try running it with `Xmx` argument, e.g.:

```
java -jar -Xmx4096M file.jar
```

Comment: I tried both -mx and -Xmx, from 3700m to 7000m.  No matter what, the memory shown in the Task Manager always maxed out at 2.1Gb

Comment: @Michael are you running a 32bit VM by any chance?

Comment: @ThomasJungblut I uninstalled the 32bit version on my machine just to make sure.  Nope, it's definitely the 64bit that I'm running